# Как правильно работать с ресурсами в Spring?

Tags: java, spring

```
-main
-webapp
  --resources
     ---folder
-WEB-INF
-test
```

Классическая структура web-проекта. Мне нужно обработать файлы в папке `folder`.

Как я делаю: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("folder")` 
 Потом делаю из этого файл и тд.
Подскажите, какие есть ещё способы работать с ресурсами в spring?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484594/spring-3-0-inject-files-as-resources работать с ресурсами можно через аннотации. (Из статьи по ссылке: `@Value("classpath:<path to file>")
private Resource cert;` )

Comment: И вот урок по ресурсам в Spring: http://spring-projects.ru/guides/lessons/lesson-3/

Comment: И вот тут интересно про доступ к статике: http://www.sql.ru/forum/951199/pravilnaya-rabota-so-staticheskimi-resursami-v-spring-proekte

Comment: чтобы `folder` был доступен таким способом - его надо положить в WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 1):

В Spring есть семейство классов для работы с ресурсами (в данном контексте ресурс это то, у чего можно получить `InputStream`). Все они реализуют интерфейс [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html):

- `ClassPathResource` позволяет находить ресурсы по всему `CLASSPATH`.
- `ByteArrayResource` оборачивает байт-массив в ресурс (чтобы отдать куда-то).
- `UrlResource` позволяет обращатсья к ресурсам по URL или к файлам (URL со схемой `file:`).
- `FileSystemResource` только для работы с файловой системой.
- `PathResource` работает с путями (`Path`) из `java.nio`.